# Undeployed application at context path with netbeans while using listener

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

There is the error i got on the run console (that's not my project, my one is in french, i found an other on a forum) :

```
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /SupMark but context failed to start
/media/Hhai/users/SupMark/nbproject/build-impl.xml:563: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

On the apache TomCat log, i've got like said in the first post, but with the listenerStop problem too :

```
16 déc. 2011 18:46:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) à l'instance de classe d'écoute com.supinfo.supmark.listener.ConnectionListener
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
```

So, before posting there, i'd search by myself a solution, which i didn't, but i've at least know where the problem is : It's cause of the listener i add !

```
@WebListener()
public class ConnectionListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    PersistenceManager.createEntityManagerFactory();
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    PersistenceManager.closeEntityManagerFactory();
}
}
```

I didn't note the import, don't think it's necessary ! Cause of the error message, i add the throw exception, same problem ! Then i delete my listener and create a new one, but let him by default, like this :

```
@WebListener()
public class ConnectionListener implements ServletContextListener {
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
}
```

And once again :

```
ECHEC - Application déployée pour le chemin de contexte /SupMark mais le démarrage du contexte a échoué
```

So if you need more informations, or if someone already dealt with a problem like mine ... PS : That works fine on eclipse , but i need to use NetBeans for derby ...

Thanks.